# Edit query string parameter on retry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got the following code structure:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://example.com",
  data:{
    final:false
  },
  retry: {
    attempt: 1,
    limit: 3,
    delay: 2000
  },
  success((data) => {
    console.log("yay!");
  }),
  error((error) => {
    if (this.retry.attempt++ <= this.retry.limit) {
      var self = this;
      if (self.retry.attempt > self.retry.limit) {
        self.data.final = true;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {$.ajax(self)}, this.retry.delay);
    }
  })
});
```

The problem is that, when the request is called the first time, the `data` parameter gets erased, and its values appended to the url as a query string.  So `data` no longer exists.  The object that gets passed into the retry call is:

```
{
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://example.com?final=false",
  retry: {
    attempt: 2,
    limit: 3,
    delay: 2000
  },
  success((data) => {
    //...
  }),
  error((error) => {
    //...
  }
}
```

How do I edit the `final` parameter of the request for the last retry?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing URL to "http://example.com?final=false" or "http://example.com?final="+false if false is a variable

Answer (score 0):

try defining your request outside the `ajax` call:

```
const request = {
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://example.com",
  data:{
    final:false
  }
};

$.ajax({...request, ...{
  retry: {
    attempt: 1,
    limit: 3,
    delay: 2000
  },
  success((data) => {
    console.log("yay!");
  }),
  error((error) => {
    if (this.retry.attempt++ <= this.retry.limit) {
      const retryRequest = {...request, ...this};
      if (this.retry.attempt > this.retry.limit) {
        retryRequest.data.final = true;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {$.ajax(retryRequest)}, this.retry.delay);
    }
  })
});
```

alternatively, if you're only dealing with the one flag that only needs to be set on the last attempt:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"http://example.com",
  retry: {
    attempt: 1,
    limit: 3,
    delay: 2000
  },
  success((data) => {
    console.log("yay!");
  }),
  error((error) => {
    if (this.retry.attempt++ <= this.retry.limit) {
      var self = this;
      if (self.retry.attempt > self.retry.limit) {
        self.data = {final: true};
      }
      setTimeout(() => {$.ajax(self)}, this.retry.delay);
    }
  })
});
```

also, fat arrow functions don't have local context, so your `error` function doesn't need to use `self`, i.e. this will work:

```
error((error) => {
  if (this.retry.attempt++ <= this.retry.limit) {
    if (this.retry.attempt > this.retry.limit) {
      this.data = {final: true};
    }
    setTimeout(() => {$.ajax(this)}, this.retry.delay);
  }
})
```